# Retrofit2 enqueue onResponse() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Function returns null before data.value is set in asynchronous onResponse().
How to make it first fetch data and then return that data?

```
fun getNews(code: String): LiveData<List<News>>{

    val call = service.getNewsByCountry(code, Constant.API_KEY)

    var data = MutableLiveData<List<News>>()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.v("retrofit", "call failed")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>?, response: Response<NewsResponse>?) {
            data.value = response!!.body()!!.articles
        }

    })

    return data
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making an asynchronous call, so data.value will not be set until that asynchronous call resolves. However, since you are generating a MutableLiveData, you should be able to observe, which will give you an update when your asynchronous call sets the value.

Comment: I know it's asynchronous, I wanted to see if there is some elegant way to deal with these kind of situations in Kotlin.
In the end I did it by observing LiveData object. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `object:Callback`

```
 accessTocken.enqueue(object : Callback<AccessToken> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AccessToken>, t: Throwable) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AccessToken>, response: Response<AccessToken>) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fun getNews(code: String): LiveData<List<News>>{

    val call = service.getNewsByCountry(code, Constant.API_KEY)
    var data = MutableLiveData<List<News>>()
    doAsync {
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.v("retrofit", "call failed")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>?, response: Response<NewsResponse>?) {
                data.value = response!!.body()!!.articles
            }

        })
    }

    return data
}
```

If not exists `doAsync` try add follow anko dependency on your `app/build.gralde`

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a more extensive answer to your question on this article.

**Before** retrofit 2.6.0 you have to call `enqueue()` and implement *callbacks*. Now it is noτ necessary anymore.

You should change from this:

```
class TodoRepository {

var client: Webservice = RetrofitClient.webservice

fun getTodo(id: Int): LiveData<Todo> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Todo>()

    client.getTodo(id).enqueue(object: Callback<Todo>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Todo>, response: Response<Todo>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                // When data is available, populate LiveData
                liveData.value = response.body()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Todo>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    })

    // Synchronously return LiveData
    // Its value will be available onResponse
    return liveData
   }
}
```

to this:

```
class TodoRepository {
  var client: Webservice = RetrofitClient.webservice

   suspend fun getTodo(id: Int) = client.getTodo(id)
}
```

Here you have the complete answer -> https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: You're right, but if you want to get response code from server (for example 200, 400 or 500), you need this callbacks.